# this.defaultValue returns undefined for select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Normal HTML dropdown menu:

```
<select name="email" id="email">
     <option value="2" selected="selected">Before redirecting to PayPal</option>
     <option value="1">After payment is successful</option>
     <option value="3">Never send email</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery `this.defaultValue` returns *'undefined'*.

Using `$(this).val()` returns *'2'*, correctly.

Why is `this.defaultValue` returning *'undefined'*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described on [**W3C**](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26091157), `defaultValue` works only with certain types of the elements

> `defaultValue` of type DOMString
> When the `type` attribute of the element has the value `"text"`, `"file"` or `"password"` (...)